# Why I can not use IF in here?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to remove and drop a table if the the table has no data or empty, so I wrote this Statement in PostgreSQL, but I am encountering an error saying `syntax error near IF`.

I can divide this to 2 different SQL statements, but I want to run this as one query.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${tableName}) > 0
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE ${tableName}
    END
```

I also tried this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM zzz > 0) THEN
    DROP TABLE zzz
END IF

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 2: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM zzz > 0
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 7
```

Comment: `IF ... THEN ... END IF`. Also that's only for plpgsql, there's no `IF` in SQL (for postgres at least).

Comment: Because in SQL there is no `IF` you need dynamic SQL and PL/pgSQL for that.

Comment: I am trying this in postgresql.

Comment: that is SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax where these kind of query constructs are allowed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with SQL, you'll have to use a `DO` statement:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM zzz) > 0 THEN
      DROP TABLE zzz;
   END IF;
END;$$;
```

Comment: That can still fail in PostgreSQL if other objects (like views) are depending on the table

Comment: Naturally. In that case you can add `CASCADE` to the `DROP` statement.

Comment: This works great but is it possible to return something if table is not empty?

Comment: No, for that you'd have to go all the way and write a function.